# How can we convert \\u003C\\u003F\\ this format unicode characters to normal html text

Tags: c#, html, unicode

\u003C\u003F\u0078\u006D\u006C\

I appreciate any guidance. Thanks

Comment: Where did those escape sequences come from? If it was JSON, then your solution may be to start using a proper JSON deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

`\u003C\u003F\u0078\u006D\u006C\` translates to `<?xml`.

Find the complete list of Unicode characters [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).

Find the complete list of XML and HTML character entities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: `U+003C` translates to `<`, `U+003F` translates to `?` and so on. Please check the links.

Comment: @Scratte - Sorry for the misunderstanding!